# D3.js stacked area chart resizing issue

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, resize, svg-animate

I have a stacked area chart using d3.js. I have a function that resizes & redraws the visualization on window.resize. The logic is to remove 10% margin and scale x/y axis according to window size.

You can see it here:

http://porwal.info/direct/demos/d3graphs/area.html

The logic works when I resize the window (zoom in or zoom out), if the window size is not near full size.  If the height is close to full height, the graph overflows the expected boundary. And for example, if you press F11 for full screen, the graph overflows.
Its not just with F11, but if I maximize, sometimes if works properly and other times it overflows.

The relevant js file is

http://porwal.info/direct/demos/d3graphs/js/area.js

Also, relevant resize functions:

```
function setACDimensions() {
    ac_container_width=$(window).innerWidth();
    ac_container_height=Math.round(0.8*$(window).innerHeight());

    $(ac_container).height(ac_container_height);
    $(ac_container).width(ac_container_width);

    var margin=(ac_margin > 10)? 10 : ac_margin;
    var factor= 1 - 2*margin/100;

    ac_width = Math.round(factor*ac_container_width);
    ac_height = Math.round(factor*ac_container_height);

    ac_origin_x=Math.round(ac_container_width * margin/100);
    ac_origin_y=Math.round(ac_container_height * margin/100);
}

function resizeAreaGraph() {
    setACDimensions();
    area_vis.attr("width", ac_width)
        .attr("height", ac_height)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ac_origin_x + "," + ac_origin_y + ")");
    redrawAreaGraph();
};


function redrawAreaGraph() {
    if(!area_graph_exists) { 
        initAreaGraph(); 
    } else { 
        bindAreaData(); 
    }

    if(area_graph_exists) {
        area_paths.data(area_stack);

        area_paths.select("path")
            .transition()
            .attr("d", function(d) { return area_fn(d.values); });


        area_paths.select("text")
            .datum(function(d) { return { name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                    return "translate(" + xx(d.value.year) + "," + yy(d.value.y0 + d.value.y / 2) + ")"; 
                    })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        area_vis.select("g .x_axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + ac_height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
        area_vis.select("g .y_axis").call(yAxis);
    }
}
```

(Full code can be seen in the js file I gave link to above).

Comment: i was not able to get it to overflow, chromium on win7 64bit

Comment: Not able to reproduce on Chrome 33, IE11 or Firefox 27 on Win7.  I suspect this is a broswer specific issue of giving bad results for `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`.  How much of an overflow are we talking about?  Is it the difference of the scroll bar widths?

Comment: Thank you for the comments & testing it out. Mine is chrome 28 on ubuntu.  I will test it with other versions and update.